# How can I add a partition that looks wavy without using an image?

Tags: html, css, frontend

So I am trying to make a front page. But first I would like to partition the page into 2 sections, but in reality 3. SO one would be, say color A, and the div would have an animation in it. The second would just blend the two pages together, eg below. Third div would be color B, with an animation.
Here is an example I have made on paint:
[image]

Now here is what I currently have:
[image]
Perhaps it would be a good idea to include some code with this question. I am using handlebars so I will only add the part that determines the sizing of the three divs.

HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/frontpage_section_1.css">
</head>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.second {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.third {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #161717
}
```

I have tried using images, SVGs, and with those options it's been hard to get them to stretch to the full size of the div at all times. That and I would like to go with something more pure css and html rather than files. I would love to get some advice on what I should look into to make the partition look good (or well to even exist).

Comment: You can't. (If you consider SVG are images.) May I recommend [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)?

Comment: You could also use something like [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) but it is probably overkill for something like this

Comment: @sinanspd paper.js seems really cool, I'm just afraid it could be a case of me biting off more than I can chew and ending up spending way too much time on just a partition on the frontpage instead of the front page as a whole. Although it would make the front page really stand out which would be a benefit.